# useAutocomplete Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined or Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

I have a problem with my autocomplete textfield. I am trying to load all Users into a var called "Mitarbeiter". As you see in the code below:

```
 const mitarbeiter = useState("");

db.collection("Mitarbeiter").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            mitarbeiter = [doc.id,doc.data()]
            console.log("MITARBEITER ",mitarbeiter);
        });
    });
```

This step is working fine. Now I am trying to load all of them into a AutoComplete textare:

```
<Autocomplete
id="combo-box-demo"
options={mitarbeiter}
onChange={e => setMit(e.target.value)}
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
style={{ width: 350 }}
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Mitarbeiter" variant="outlined" />}
                    />
```

But the error shows when I use the variable : `var mitarbeiter`:

> useAutocomplete  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

And a different error when I use the variable :  `const mitarbeiter = useState("");`:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Where is my mistake?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You are using useState not correctly. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook) is a doc about this hook.
So try to do next:

```
const [mitarbeiter, setMitarbeiter] = useState([]);
```

after in section of getting your mitarbeiter do the following (Ussually this placed in [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)):

```
db.collection("Mitarbeiter").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // in case if doc.id,doc.data()
        setMitarbeiter(doc.id,doc.data()) // set array data to mitarbeiter
        console.log("MITARBEITER ",mitarbeiter);
    });
});
```

End in the end you should use Autocomplite

```
<Autocomplete
 id="combo-box-demo"
 options={mitarbeiter}
 onChange={e => setMit(e.target.value)}
 getOptionLabel={(option) => option && option.title}
 style={{ width: 350 }}
 renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Mitarbeiter" variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didnt know that. But it still shows me the error "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: @LEON you should attach the whole component